# How to assign result of NSURLSession to a variable in same method?

Tags: objective-c, json, ios7, nsdictionary, nsurlsession

To say I'm new to Objective-C would be a huge understatement. I'm primarily a Ruby/Rails developer and it completely spoiled me when it comes to OOP & programming in general.

After getting tired of reading tutorials, I decided to try to use NSRULSession to hit one of my Rails apps (an Elder Scrolls Online skill planner) & display some of the JSON response on my iOS app. Delegates make no sense, I'm not sure how to break this functionality up into methods, etc, so I thought I'd keep it simple & do it all in the viewDidLoad() method (yes, I know it's bad practice).

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    __block NSDictionary *skillData; // No clue what __block is

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.esomix.com/skill_builds/17.json"] completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
        NSLog(@"%@", json[@"name"]);
        skillData = json;
    }];

    [dataTask resume];

    UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 100, 200, 100)];
    myLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0/255.0 green:255.0/255.0 blue:255.0/255.0 alpha:1];
    [self.view addSubview:myLabel];

    NSLog(@"%@", skillData[@"name"]);
    NSLog(@"bottom of method");
}
```

After lots of toying around, I figured out that despite the NSURLSession code before my NSLogs at the bottom, it returns its data after they're rendered. No wonder my label.text (not shown) wasn't getting set! Here's the order of my three NSLogs:

```
(null)
bottom of method
Single-Target Lockdown Sniper
```

I guess my question is what's the simplest, proper way to make an JSON API request and use the data to generate a UI element/other tasks after the data has returned. Thanks so much!

Comment: Put your code inside that completion block, after 'skillData = json;'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of clarifying points:

1. You ask

   > what's the simplest, proper way to make an JSON API request and use the data to generate a UI element/other tasks after the data has returned

   In short, use the JSON response inside the completion block, not after it, for example:

   ```
   - (void)viewDidLoad 
   {
       [super viewDidLoad];

       NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
       NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.esomix.com/skill_builds/17.json"] completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

           NSDictionary *skillData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

           // use `skillData` here

           // finally, any UI/model updates should happen on main queue

           dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
               UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 100, 200, 100)];
               myLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0/255.0 green:255.0/255.0 blue:255.0/255.0 alpha:1];
               myLabel.text = skillData[@"name"]; // or whatever you wanted from `skillData`
               [self.view addSubview:myLabel];
           });
       }];

       [dataTask resume];

       // don't try to use `skillData` here, as the above block runs asynchronously,
       // and thus `skillData` will not have been set yet
   }
   ```
2. The purpose of the `__block` qualifier is to let the block update a variable whose scope is outside the block. But, because the `NSURLSessionDataTask` runs asynchronously, there's no point in trying to reference `skillData` outside that block (because the `viewDidLoad` method will have completed well before the `completionHandler` for the `NSURLSessionDataTask` is invoked, as illustrated by your `NSLog` results).

   So, since there's no point in referencing `skillData` outside the block, then there's no point in defining it with the `__block` qualifier outside of the block. Just make it a local variable inside the block. If you want to update your model (or perhaps some properties of the view controller), you can do that (but when dealing with class properties and ivars, no `__block` qualifier is needed).

Comment: By the way, you'd obviously check to see if the `data` in the `completionHandler` was `nil`, and if so, perhaps examine the `error` object (e.g. to handle basic lack of internet connectivity or if the server is down). Likewise, when you do `JSONObjectWithData`, you'd obviously check to make sure `skillData` was not `nil`, and handle that error, too (e.g. if the server is up, but the URL resulted in a 404 - not found error). I was trying to keep it simple, but make sure you do the necessary error handling.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It worked perfectly. This is such a bizarrely different world than Rails and it makes my head want to explode. I'll attempt to figure out how to check for an error, but that works now. Not sure why I got downvoted though. It was a legitimate question :)