# IOS: After API call, may updates to Core Data be done in background thread?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsurlsession

As part of sync operation, I grab a lot of data from API using the NSSession Object as recommended by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20917297/how-to-assign-result-of-nsurlsession-to-a-variable-in-same-method):

```
 NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
        NSURLSessionDataTask *data = [session dataTaskWithURL:dataUrl completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
            // use `Data` here
             if (data !=nil) {
             [self processData:data];//this currently includes saving to CoreData
            }
            // finally, any UI/model updates should happen on main queue

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                //do what you want with data
                NSLog(@"back in main queue");
                if (data==nil) {
                    NSLog(@"no data from api");
                }
                else {
                    [self.tableView setNeedsDisplay];
                    [self.tableView reloadData];
                }
            });
        }];

        [data resume];
```

My question is, is it okay to save the data to CoreData in the background thread, or is it better to do that in the completion block/main thread?  Right now I am doing it in the background thread.  There is a long delay, however, before the tableview fully loads and as part of troubleshooting this--it occurred to me this might be the problem.

Thank you for suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not do it on the main thread. But how you should implement it instead depends on your Core Data stack and what you actually do in your processData function. In general, in these import scenarios, it is best practice to do the save operation from a child context on a private queue.

Apple has some example code [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Concurrency.html).

Excerpt from that page:

> In this example an array of data has been originally received as a JSON payload. You then create a new NSManagedObjectContext that is defined as a private queue. The new context is set as a child of the main queue context that runs the application. From there you call performBlock: and do the actual NSManagedObject creation inside of the block that is passed to performBlock:. Once all of the data has been consumed and turned into NSManagedObject instances, you call save on the private context, which moves all of the changes into the main queue context without blocking the main queue.

Comment: Ok.  Sounds like a bear.  I do a lot of processing so looks like I will have to spend a lot of time sorting out which MOC is being used.

Comment: To confirm, processData should go where shown above?

Comment: Right, working with many MOCs can be a pain. But figuring out which one is being used is easy, because every MO has a (weak) reference to its MOC. So unless you have dealloced your MOC, you can just refer to the MOC of any given MO.

Comment: Re processData: You could improve your design by having that function do the hard work on a private queue, saving to disk and only then return to the main thread and trigger the UI update. Right now you're hanging in that DataTask queue while you do the processing. Given that you do the save to disk operation in a background thread, it might happen at the same time that processData returns and you call the main thread to update the UI, which might update its MOC from disk. So that could result in a stuttering UI. As I said, it depends on what you do in processData, so I'm just guessing here ;)

Comment: There is a lot of stuff in process data. Rather than save the whole JSON object I first compare each item to the list of items in core data and save it as new if no item exists.  The API on the server uses a lot of joins so to save these on core data I also end up creating new managed objects in other entities for each primary item save.  A lot of hitting the disk.  It has led to a fragile rfragile sync operation where I am afraid that not everything is thread safe--ie I may be hitting the singleton model at inconvenient times etc.